# Creating a React Context with TypeScript to share state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I am trying to create a `React Context` with TypeScript to share state between components. When creating the Context, I tried passing `null` as the initial value.

```js
// contexts.ts file
import { createContext } from 'react';
export const AuthorContext = createContext(null);
```

But when trying to pass the `state value` and `setter function` to the value of the `Provider` this would cause problems because *not assignable to type null*.

```js
const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");

<AuthorContext.Provider value={{ message, setMessage }}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/first`} component={FirstContextContainer} />
        <Route path={`${path}/second`} component={SecondContextContainer} />
    </Switch>
</AuthorContext.Provider>
```

So I tried creating an `interface` with the type definitions the error message gave me.

```js
interface IStateStringDef {
  stateVal: string;
  setStateVal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}
```

And update my `Context` and `Provider`.

```js
// contexts.ts file
export const AuthorContext = createContext<IStateStringDef | null>(null); 

// file where provider is
<AuthorContext.Provider value={{ stateVal: message, setStateVal: setMessage }}>
```

And this works but doesn't seem like the most correct and elegant way to do it, what is the correct way for creating and using a context in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need a interface or type for context (like IStateStringDef).

```
interface IStateStringDef {
    message: string;
    setMessage: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}
```

And you do not need
`null`,
you can just pass the default values to context like `createContext<IStateStringDef>({ message: '', setMessage: () => {});`

Comment: So it is normal to do it this way?

Comment: Yeah but without `null`

Comment: Thank you, it just seemed weird to use `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>` as type in the interface but if that is the correct way, I will use it.